# What is the difference between let and var in a multiple variable definition?

Tags: javascript, variables, environment-variables, global-variables

**Syntax error:**

```js
let admin,
names = "Bob",
admin = names;

alert(admin);
```

Using the var variable is not recommended, but could such a definition cause an error?
**"var" No error:**

```js
var admin,
names = "Bob",
admin = names;

alert(admin);
```

**Different syntax of the let variable (No error):**

```js
let admin, names;

names = "Bob";

admin = names;

alert(admin);
```

I've explored the difference between the var and let variable, but I don't fully understand the differences here.

**What are the differences between the codes?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare variables while using commas in a single statement, you're declaring a variable for each comma (plus the first one). For example:

```
let admin,
names = "Bob",
admin = names;
```

is equivalent to, separated out into 3 statements:

```
let admin;
let names = "Bob";
let admin = names;
```

But variables declared with `let` and `const` cannot be initialized more than once; in a given scope, there must be exactly one line that initializes them with `let` or `const`.

In contrast, variables declared with `var` do not have such a limitation. `var`s essentially get hoisted up to the top of the function. So

```
var foo = 5;
foo = 10;
```

is like

```
var foo;
foo = 5;
foo = 10;
```

and duplicate `var` declarations in the same scope aren't a problem, since they'll all refer to the same hoisted identifier at the top. That's why your second snippet doesn't throw an error.

Your third snippet doesn't throw because the `admin` and `names` are each initialized exactly once:

```
let admin, names;
```

is like

```
let admin;
let names;
```

which is fine. *Assigning* to a variable multiple times isn't an issue (as long as the variable isn't declared with `const`); it's just the *initialization* of a `let` variable must happen only exactly once.

Comment: Because they're separate variable names. If you tried to declare the *same* variable more than once (either with a comma with the same `let`, or in a separate statement after a semicolon), an error would be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that you can declare a variable more than once with [`var`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-variable-statement), but not with [`let`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-let-and-const-declarations):

```js
var v = 42;
var v;
console.log(v);
```

```js
let l = 42;
let l;
// SyntaxError: Cannot declare a let variable twice: 'l'.
```

Actually, in your example, we get bitten even earlier by [14.3.1.1 *Declarations and the Variable Statement* – *Let and Const Declarations* – *Static Semantics: Early Errors*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-let-and-const-declarations-static-semantics-early-errors) clause 2:

> It is a Syntax Error if the BoundNames of *BindingList* contains any duplicate entries.

```js
let l, l;
// SyntaxError: Cannot declare a let variable twice: 'l'.
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's simple! var and let are both used for variable declaration in typescript but the difference between them is that var is function scoped and let is block scoped.
Let's see an example below.**

```js
// calling x after defining 
var x = 5; 
document.write(x, "\n"); 
  
// calling y after defining  
let y = 10; 
document.write(y, "\n"); 
  
// calling var z before defining will return undefined 
document.write(z, "\n"); 
var z = 2; 
  
// calling let a before defining will give error 
document.write(a); 
let a = 3;
```